# instagram with expressjs not working, getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, instagram-api

I keep getting 404 error, what am I doing wrong? I have all the client_id, secret and token keys.

```
var inst = require('instagram-node').instagram();
var app = express();
inst.use({
  client_id: '-',
  client_secret: '-',
  access_token: '-'
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  inst.user_self_feed(function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
    if (err){
        res.send(err.body);
        console.log('error');
      }
      else
        res.send(medias);
  });
  // res.render('home');
});
```